# Full Calendar Event Data

Tags: php, mysql, events, calendar, fullcalendar

I'm thinking of using [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) as an event calendar on a website.

My question: Is there any documentation or examples of using PHP/MySQL to store an access event data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing this too, and I had wished that there was a more complete example of the PHP/MySQL side, since I'm usually an ASP.NET/MS-SQL guy, so I had to spend more time than I would have liked on some basic stuff.  Here's an outline of what I did.  It's pretty basic.

First, I created a table in MySQL that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `event_url` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `all_day` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Then, I wrote a PHP program named json-events.php, which I used as the event source for the calendar. In this program, you first need to get the start and end dates for the currently-displayed calendar:

```
$start_date = $_GET['start'];
$end_date = $_GET['end'];
```

Then, you need to run a SQL query to get events in that window:

```
$sqlcommand = "select * from events 
where start_date between from_unixtime($start_date) and from_unixtime($end_date)
or end_date between from_unixtime($start_date) and from_unixtime($end_date)
order by start_date";
```

Then, put together an array with the results:

```
$event_array = array();
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $event_array[] = array(
        'id' => $record['id'],
        'title' => $record['title'],
        'start' => $record['start_date'],
        'end' => $record['end_date'],
        'url' => $record['event_url'],
        'allDay' => $record['all_day']
    );
}
```

Finally, JSON encode it and echo it:

```
echo json_encode($event_array);
```

This seems to work.  I'm not that familiar with the way date/time fields are handled in MySQL and PHP, so I'm not sure if I'm doing this in the most efficient manner.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to implement a PHP page that retrieves event data from a MySQL database and returns it in JSON format. You would then use that URL as a [JSON feed source](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/#options) for the calendar.

There is sample code on [the FullCalendar GitHub repository](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/tree/master/demos).

And there is a demo showing [how to listen to events if something changes in the calendar](http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.1/demos/json.html).